# Custom AJAX discount-form not processing coupons

Tags: cart, ce-1.9.0.1, coupon, coupon-codes, jquery

Running Magento 1.9.0.1 CE

I've created an AJAX version of the discount-form used in Magento to process coupons in Magento with the help of this tutorial: http://www.lelandcope.com/2012/04/how-to-create-an-ajax-coupon-discount-code-box-in-magento/

Basically, I left the previous discount form in place (verifying that there were no conflicts) so that I could verify my coupons quickly in case my AJAX form didn't work.

The gist is, my AJAX form is rejecting EVERY coupon. Here is the code summary.

AJAX Form HTML:

```
<div class="box"> 
  <strong class="ttl">DISCOUNT CODE</strong> 
  <p>Enter your coupon code if you  have one</p> 
  <form id="discountcode-form" action="<?= $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/couponPost') ?>" name="discountcode-form" method="post"> 
    <div class="text discount-code"><input type="text" name="coupon_code" value="SUBMIT YOUR CODE" /></div> 
    <input type="submit" class="btn-apply" value="APPLY"/> 
  </form> 
</div>
```

AJAX Form jQuery (in no-conflict mode):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#discountcode-form').submit(function(e) 
{ 
    console.log("entering script");
  e.preventDefault(); 

  jQuery.ajax({ 
    url:jQuery('#discountcode-form').attr('action'), 
    type:'POST', 
    data:'ajax=true&'+jQuery('#discountcode-form').serialize(), 
    success:function(data) 
    { 
      if(data != '') 
      { 
        console.log("error messages") 
      } 
    } 
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

And finally, the piece of the puzzle I believe to be responsible for the issue - CartController.php:

```
<?php 

  require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php'; 

  class MyModules_CouponProcessor_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController 
  { 
    function couponPostAction() 
    { 
      // if not ajax have parent deal with result 

      if(!isset($_POST['ajax'])) 
      { 
        parent::couponPostAction(); 
        return; 
      } 

      $msg = ''; 

      $couponCode = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code'); 
          if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('remove') == 1) { 
              $couponCode = ''; 
          } 
          $oldCouponCode = $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode(); 

          if (!strlen($couponCode) && !strlen($oldCouponCode)) { 
              $this->_goBack(); 
              return; 
          } 

          try { 
              $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true); 
              $this->_getQuote()->setCouponCode(strlen($couponCode) ? $couponCode : '') 
                  ->collectTotals() 
                  ->save(); 

              if ($couponCode) { 
                  if ($couponCode == $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode()) { 
                      $this->_getSession()->addSuccess( 
                          $this->__('Coupon code "%s" was applied.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($couponCode)) 
                      ); 
                  } 
                  else { 
                     $msg = $this->__('Coupon code "%s" is not valid.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($couponCode)); 
                  } 
              } else { 
                  $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Coupon code was canceled.')); 
              } 

          } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) { 
              $msg = $e->getMessage(); 
          } catch (Exception $e) { 
               $msg = $this->__('Cannot apply the coupon code.'); 
              Mage::logException($e); 
          } 

      echo $msg; 
    } 
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong in my CartController? The AJAX seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your JS a little bit(change ajax post url)

```
     var url = jQuery('#discountcode-form').attr('action');
     url = url.replace("checkout/cart", "CouponProcessor/cart");
     jQuery.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: 'POST',
         data: 'ajax=true&' + jQuery('#discountcode-form').serialize(),
         success: function(data){
             if (data != ''){
                 // Display error message however you would like 
             }
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm too searching for the answer, is that your solved?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#discount-coupon-form').submit(function(e) 
    { 
        console.log("entering script");
      e.preventDefault(); 

      jQuery.ajax({ 
        url:jQuery('#discountcode-form').attr('action'), 
        type:'POST', 
        data:'ajax=true&'+jQuery('#discount-coupon-form').serialize(), 
        success:function(data) 
        { 
          if(data != '') 
          { 
            console.log("error messages") 
          } 
        } 
      }); 
    }); 
    </script>
    <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```