# Apply Magento Coupon in Ajax Without Redirecting to Cart Page

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, ajax, coupon-codes

I have coupon code on sidebar on my product categories list, cart and checkout page. Whenever I'm trying to add coupon code while being on the product or category list page or checkout page, it is taking me to the cart page. Is there any way I can make it apply on the same page  without redirecting or reloading with the help of ajax?

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml(); ?>
<div class="coupon bg-gray">
<form id="discount-coupon-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/coupon') ?>" name="discountcode-form" method="post">
    <div class="discount">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('Discount Codes') ?></h2>
        <div class="discount-form">
            <!--<label for="coupon_code"><?php echo $this->__('Discount Codes') ?></label>-->
            <input type="hidden" name="remove" id="remove-coupone" value="0" />
            <!--<div class="field-wrapper">-->
                <input class=" form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Coupon Code" id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCouponCode()) ?>" />
                <!--<div class="button-wrapper">-->
                   <!-- <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Apply') ?>" class="btn-danger" onclick="discountForm.submit(false)" value="<?php echo $this->__('Apply') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('REEDEM COUPON') ?></span></span></button>--><?php $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/onepage_link'); ?>   <?php if ($block->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()):?>       <?php if ($block->isDisabled()):?>               <input type="submit" title="Minimum order should be Rs.300 or above" value="<?php echo $this->__('REEDEM COUPON') ?>" class="btn-danger btn-checkoutno-checkout" disabled="disabled" />                    <?php else: ?>                   <input type="submit" title="Minimum order should be Rs.300 or above" value="<?php echo $this->__('REEDEM COUPON') ?>" class="btn-danger"  />
                   <?php endif?>    <?php endif?>                                  


 <?php if(strlen($this->getCouponCode())): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Cancel') ?>" class="button2 cancel-coupon" onclick="discountForm.submit(true)" value="<?php echo $this->__('Cancel') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
                        </button>
                    <?php endif;?>

                <!--</div>-->
            <!--</div>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

function updateCoupon(reqid) {

var reqid;

if(reqid == 2) {  $('coupon_code').setValue('');  }

$('discount-coupon-form').request({

method: 'post',

onComplete: payment.onComplete,

onSuccess: payment.onSave,

onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout),

})

}

//]]>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot issue in your code.

JavaScript `is wrong.`you have call `opcheckout.js` function `payment.payment.onSave` and  c`heckout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout`), etc which `does not work on all pages`.

So you need to `Custom code` which will apply coupon  code on ajax on all pages

**You can follow the link for full your requirement:**

[Custom AJAX discount-form not processing coupons](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33671/custom-ajax-discount-form-not-processing-coupons)

[lelandcope](http://www.lelandcope.com/2012/04/how-to-create-an-ajax-coupon-discount-code-box-in-magento/)

Comment: Thanks.. I followed the same tutorial but it is not working.. coupon code is also not working nor ajax..It is giving me "error message"

Answer (score 0):

I have created one module for discount code popup which has method to apply code without reloading cart page

Here is [link](https://github.com/vnahalpara/discountpopup) for this module for reference

in your javascript method updateCoupon() you have call ajax method which calls controller action in that you need to add following code to apply code without refreshing page Here **applyAction** is my ajax action

```
public function applyAction()
    {
        $response = array();
        $couponCode = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('remove') == 1) {
            $couponCode = '';
        }
        $oldCouponCode = $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode();
        if (!strlen($couponCode) && !strlen($oldCouponCode)) {
            $message = "Please enter valid code";
            $response['error'] = 1;
        }
        try {
            $codeLength = strlen($couponCode);
            $isCodeLengthValid = $codeLength && $codeLength <= Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart::COUPON_CODE_MAX_LENGTH;
            $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $this->_getQuote()->setCouponCode($isCodeLengthValid ? $couponCode : '')
                ->collectTotals()
                ->save();
            if ($codeLength) {
                if ($isCodeLengthValid && $couponCode == $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode()) {
                        $message = $this->__('Coupon code "%s" was applied.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode));
                    $this->_getSession()->setCartCouponCode($couponCode);
                } else {
                        $message = $this->__('Coupon code "%s" is not valid.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode));
                        $response['error'] = 1;
                }
            } else {
                $message = $this->__('Coupon code was canceled.');
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            $response['error'] = 1;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $response['error'] = 1;
            $message = $this->__('Cannot apply the coupon code.');
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $response['message'] = $message;
        $response['code'] = $couponCode;
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
    }
```